# I need to setup SSMS to run on a different domain (runas.exe) How do I help my users identify the path to the ssms.exe file?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server` folder, these subfolders are present:

```
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
Client SDK
```

For some of my users, SSMS is installed in the 130 folder, others in the 140 folder.

How do I help my users discover where the ssms.exe file is located for SSMS?  When I review the properties of the SSMS shortcut in the Start menu, the only option is to see where the shortcut is located (not the actual ssms.exe file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way (reading registry perhaps?)

SSMS path also depends on 32-bit vs. 64-bit too

To make it worse, SSMS 18 (Preview) is completely different but easier going forward (path is c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18)

Here is a useful website for previous SSMS.exe paths

https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/where-do-i-find-sql-server-management-studio

> A: The executable file for SQL Server Management Studio is found in
>   different locations depending on the version of SQL Server that you’re
>   using. For SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2012 the executable for SSMS
>   is called ssme.exe.
>
> For SQL Server 2014 is found in the following directory: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
>
> For SQL Server 2012 you can find SSMS at:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
>
> For SQL Server 2008 R2 you can find SSMS at:
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
>
> For the older SQL Server 2005 instances SSMS file was called SqlWb.exe
>   and it’s located at:
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe

Answer (score 0):

> How do I help my users discover where the ssms.exe file is located for
>   SSMS? When I review the properties of the SSMS shortcut in the Start
>   menu, the only option is to see where the shortcut is located (not the
>   actual ssms.exe file).

May be you just looked at the wrong place?

The shortcut points to the file location of `ssms.exe`:

[image]

Another way is to find the version of `SSMS` itself:
Help menu -> About...

[image]

Version 13 lives in 130 folder, 12 in 120, etc